# Playwright HTML report

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Running multiple test files and the results are stored in the index.html file but only the last file cases are stored in the index.html other results are not stored in the result.html file. How to see all the test case results in the index.html file.

Comment: Please share the relevant code of your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Allure report. It saves the history of all test runs by default. You can find the documentation [at Allure for Playwright](https://www.npmjs.com/package/allure-playwright)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).